# Can an Elastic Beanstalk environment be updated in Cloudformation without affecting the version deployed to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment using Cloudformation. I have to create an ApplicationVersion just to get it started and feed it into the definition of the environment. I create other ApplicationVersions and deploy them to the cluster in other ways (CodePipeline).

Now, every time I need to update the Cloudformation stack to change some other infrastructure, even though it doesn't list that as a potential resource change, it rolls back the ApplicationVersion to the initial one, and I'm having to manually update the environment to the latest version again.

I know what's going on - Cloudformation is just trying to keep the stack as the template describes it. I only ever defined the initial ApplicationVersion because it's a requirement for the Beanstalk environment. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5):

CloudFormation wants to be in control. Depending on the stack updates you perform, CloudFormation will re-create the version according to what's defined in the template.

Instead of deploying your version from Code Pipeline directly to Elastic Beanstalk, do the following:

1. Don't hard code the initial version into your CloudFormation template.
2. Have the version being deployed hooked to an input parameter to your CloudFormation stack. For example, have a input parameter be the version build number, and construct in your template a URL to that as your version source.
3. When you deploy, instruct Code Pipeline to update your stack with the updated build number. CloudFormation should take over by building a new URL and deploying the version.

**An Example:**

Assuming you have a parameter `ZipBucket` and `ZipObject` in your stack, you can do the following on your `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion` resource:

```
"SourceBundle"    : {
    "S3Bucket" : {
        "Ref" : "ZipBucket"
    },
    "S3Key"    : {
        "Ref" : "ZipObject"
    }
}
```

Another option is to have a `BuildNumber` parameter, and then use `Fn::Join` in the `S3Key` property to build a URL out of the build number.

Comment: Parameters! Didn't think of those, they can be useful. But what do I do to create the stack in the first place, when the initial application version doesn't exist yet? I create the application itself in CloudFormation too, same as application version.

Comment: Just have a "hello world" version sitting in S3 if you don't have an actual build of your application ready.

Comment: Which is pretty much what I have, I create it in the `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion` resource, and I'm having to reference it in the `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` resource. Actually I'm not sure how to parameterize that.

Comment: See my example.

Comment: Hey I have a question about this. When you update the application version in the cf template and deploy, does cf delete the old version or leave the previous one? I tried to deploy EB with terraform but it didn't work right because terraform would delete the previous app version before deploying the new one- maybe cf doesn't have this problem?

Comment: @red888 Yes, CFN will create a new version and delete the old version. Basically, it's replacing the resource in your CFN template. If I recall, the new version is created first, then the old version is deleted (but I may be wrong, and if I'm right, it may change in the future). However, the order should not matter because the old version will have already been deployed to the EC2 instances. CFN will not delete the files from S3 since those are not managed by CFN (in this case).

Comment: thats a problem then because it breaks the EB rollback feature. if you use CF like that you cant roll back to a previous version because its been deleted. even if the package is still in s3 its no longer registered with the EB application

Comment: @red888 in case of a rollback, CFN will re-create the old app version if it was deleted.

Comment: hmm yes but I mean EB rollback. You'd miss out on having a big list of previous versions you can redeploy to the environment at will. also CF rollback would also rollback any environment changes that might have occurred between versions of the cf template- instead of just deploying a version of the application

Comment: @red88 So that's not a "rollback" (in CFN/EB terminology), that's a re-deploy of an old version. And in that case, you still do it via CFN (not EB). Just deploy via CFN the old version, as if it were the next version. Always deploy forwards (even to an old version).

Comment: When you're using CFN to deploy EB, just modify anything via CFN. Don't try to circumvent things by going to EB directly. I use this in production daily. Going forwards in versions, backwards, etc. It works beautifully.

Comment: I can deploy a version 2 months old simply by updating my CFN parameter to point to the old version in S3.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with Elastic Beanstalk, CodePipeline and CloudFormation and worked out a way to achieve something similar to what you desire (I think).

I used the CloudFormation CLI (`create-stack`) and a single template from the command line to create:

- An initial Elastic Beanstalk application and environment using a "Hello, World" application that I had previously upload to an S3 bucket
- A web hook for GitHub integration
- A CodePipeline continuous delivery pipeline

The stack creation was successful and I initially had my "Hello, World" application running on Elastic Beanstalk. I was then able to deploy my actual application via the GitHub web hook and CodePipeline which overwrote the placeholder app.

I was worried that when I made changes to the environment (again using the CloudFormation CLI, this time with `create-change-set` and `execute-change-set`) I was going to redeploy the "Hello, World" app and overwrite my *real* one but this wasn't the case. My GitHub-sourced app was still the one deployed after applying the change set. Note that changes to `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion` will result in a new application being deployed on Elastic Beanstalk and the *real* version being overwritten.

It's an imperfect solution and I am not sure why AWS has designed the Elastic Beanstalk-CloudFormation-CodePipeline integration as such and it feels weird having to first deploy a dummy application before the real thing. I have experienced similar headaches with Lambdas, so I am guessing it is by design rather than oversight.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given above seem to be incorrect - or perhaps something has changed in AWS since they were written.

In my experience, any change to the `SourceBundle` in `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion` (whether the resource is declared separately or as part of the `ApplicationVersions` parameter of `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application`) will result in an error executing the changeset. The error I am getting is "You cannot update ApplicationVersions." It does not seem to matter whether I change the description or not.

The only solution I have been able to come up with thus far is to point my SourceBundle to a url that will not change. For example, `develop` for the development environment, `main` for production. I just need to make sure my latest code is deployed there before I issue any change set that could cause the version to be re-deployed.

If I'm missing something here I would love to learn if my approach could be improved.